# How pthread_once() is implemented internally?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, posix

Do we use any locking mechanism inside pthread_once()? What is the cost of using pthread_once() instead of using pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() in the threadsafe singleton class?

Comment: Sounds like it could be done with a simple atomic read/write. Plus, it doesn't seem to lock at all, if I read it correctly.

Comment: If you're not going to ask about a specific platform, the answer is, "whatever way the designers of your pthreads library thought was best on that platform".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec does not define how `pthread_once` and `pthread_mutex_lock` must be implemented, but only how they must behave, so different platforms will have different implementations.

It is generally possible to make `pthread_once` simpler than a mutex (since all it requires is an atomic test-and-set operation, and no blocking), but I would also suspect that `pthread_mutex_lock` likely received more optimization because it is much more widely used.

If you care about performance, you will have to write a benchmark and run it on the platform you are targeting, and choose the one that's faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can read directly the glibc implementation of  [pthread_once](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_once.c;h=beaeb79ef8afe76af809d01e45851300a391f627;hb=HEAD)

You are lucky because recently glibc team unified all the different implementations across the the supported architectures. They were able to replace pure assembly with modern C code that also make use of C11 atomics support